# Play 2.5 - slick: Database connection with heroku

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, playframework, slick

It is the first time I deploy a Play app (with slick) on Heroku. Everything is working well, but after a certain moment of inactivity, all datas I have stored in my **database disappear**...

In heroku, I have **Heroku Postgres** add-ons with **plan Hobby Dev**. Maybe it is because of this plan?

Or is it because of my configuration?

My "**Procfile**":

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/square-it-wtf -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

My Database config from **application.conf**:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver=org.h2.Driver
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"

db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres"
db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}
```

My **build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.187",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  ...

)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that the data is probably disappearing because it is being stored in the in-memory H2 database, which is lost after the process restarts (which happens automatically on Heroku). The Heroku database is persistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably lies in your configuration. `db.default.*` entries are   [ignored by Slick](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlickMigrationGuide#Database-configuration), so your app probably is connected to an H2 in memory database, and not Postgres.

Just update your config to point Slick to the right database:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
```

Or

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slick.dbs.default.db.properties.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
```

Comment: For more info see the PlaySlick documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlick

Comment: Thank you!!! (I have try that, but I had an other error that I did not see in the flow of logs... Sorry for disturbing! ^^)